# How to do a recursive prompt in Yeoman with promises?

Tags: javascript, recursion, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm trying to figure out how to do a recursive prompt with a yeoman generator using promises. I am trying to produce a form generator that will first ask for a name for the form component and then ask for a name (that will be used as an id) for each input (ie: firstName, lastName, username, etc.). I've found answers for this question using callbacks but I would like to stick with promises. Below is the code I have so far and what I am attempting to do for the recursion but is not working. Any help and advice is appreciated thank you in advance!

```
const Generator = require('yeoman-generator')

const questions = [
  { type: 'input',
    name: 'name',
    message: 'What is the name of this form?',
    default: 'someForm'
  },
  {
    type: 'input',
    name: 'input',
    message: 'What is the name of the input?'
  },
  {
    type: 'confirm',
    name: 'askAgain',
    message: 'Is there another input to add?'
  }

]

module.exports = class extends Generator {


  prompting() {
    return this.prompt(questions).then((answers) => {
      if (answers.askAgain) {
        this.prompting()
      }
       this.userOptions = answers
       this.log(this.userOptions)
    })
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone that stumbles across this post looking for an answer this is what I ended up doing to make it work. As you can see in my Form class that extends Generator I have a method called prompting() in there. This is a method recognized by Yeoman's loop as a priority and it will not leave this method until something is returned. Since I'm returning a promise it will wait until my promise is finished before moving on. For my first prompt that's exactly what I need but for the second one to happen in prompting2 you can add

```
const done = this.async()
```

at the start of your method. This tells yeoman that you are going to have some asynchronous code happen and not to move past the method containing this until done is executed. If you do not use this and have another priority method in your class after it, such as writing() for when you are ready to produce your generated code, then yeoman will move past your method without waiting for your asynchronous code to finish. And you can see in my method prompting2() that I recursively call it whenever the user states that there is another input to name and it will continue doing so until they say there is not another input to name. I'm sure there is a better way to do this but it is working great for me this way. I hope this helps anyone that is looking for a way to do this!

```
const Generator = require('yeoman-generator')

const questions = [
    { type: 'input',
      name: 'name',
      message: 'What is the name of this form?',
      default: 'someForm'
    }
]

const names = [
 {
   type: 'input',
   name: 'inputs',
   message: 'What is the name of the input?',
   default: '.input'
 },
 {
   type: 'confirm',
   name: 'another',
   message: "Is there another input?",
   default: true
 }
]

const inputs = []

class Form extends Generator {

  prompting() {
    return this.prompt(questions).then((answers) => {
      this.formName = answers.name
      this.log(this.formName)
   })
  }

  prompting2 () {
     const done = this.async()
     return this.prompt(names).then((answers) => {
      inputs.push(answers.inputs)
      if (answers.another) this.prompting2()
      else {
       this.inputs = inputs
       this.log(this.inputs)
       done()
      }
    })
  }

}

module.exports = Form
```

Comment: `this.async` isn't absolutely necessary. Instead you can return `return this.prompting2()` to chain promise resolution. That's not Yeoman specific, this is how Promise are working. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I will edit my answer